# How can I get my merge sort working in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, sorting, merge

I can't seem to get my merge sort working.

I'm getting a "Trying to access array offset on value of type null in" error

```
<?php     
// Sorting class
class Sort {
    // ****** MERGE SORT ****** //

    // Main call for merge sort
    public static function mergeSortAscending($array) {
        return self::mergeSortAscendingSort($array, 0, count($array) - 1);
    }

    // Sort portion of merge sort
    private static function mergeSortAscendingSort($array, $leftIndex, $rightIndex) {
        var_dump($array);
        if($leftIndex < $rightIndex) {
            // Finds mid point
            $midPoint = intdiv(($leftIndex + $rightIndex), 2);

            // Sort first part and second part
            $array = self::mergeSortAscendingSort($array, $leftIndex, $midPoint);
            $array = self::mergeSortAscendingSort($array, $midPoint + 1, $rightIndex);

            // Merge the sorted halves
            return self::mergeSortAscendingMerge($array, $leftIndex, $midPoint, $rightIndex);
        }
    }

    // Merge portion of merge sort
    private static function mergeSortAscendingMerge($array, $leftIndex, $midPoint, $rightIndex) {
        // Find sizes of subarrays to be merged
        $size1 = $midPoint - $leftIndex + 1;
        $size2 = $rightIndex - $midPoint;

        // Copy items into subarrays
        $array1;
        $array2;

        for($i = 0; $i < $size1; $i++) {
            $array1[$i] = $array[$leftIndex + $i];
        }
        for($j = 0; $j < $size2; $j++) {
            $array2[$i] = $array[$midPoint + 1 + $j];
        }

        // Merge Temp arrays

        // Initial indexes of first and second subarrays
        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;


        // Initial index of merged subarry array
        $k = $l;
        while ($i < $size1 && $j < $size2) {
            if ($array1[$i] <= $array2[$j]) {
                $array[$k] = $array1[$i];
                $i++;
            }
            else {
                $array[$k] = $array2[$j];
                $j++;
            }
            $k++;
        }

        /* Copy remaining elements of array1[] if any */
        while ($i < $size) {
            $array[$k] = $array1[$i];
            $i++;
            $k++;
        }
 
        /* Copy remaining elements of array2[] if any */
        while ($j < $size) {
            $array[$k] = $array2[$j];
            $j++;
            $k++;
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need to give some test cases and show where the problem is ( a full error message would help).

Comment: You're not defining a type for $array1 and $array2. You need to actually define it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

as @aynber pointed in a comment you need to define that `$array1` and `$array2` are arrays.

```php
// Merge portion of merge sort
private static function mergeSortAscendingMerge($array, $leftIndex, $midPoint, $rightIndex) {
    // Find sizes of subarrays to be merged
    $size1 = $midPoint - $leftIndex + 1;
    $size2 = $rightIndex - $midPoint;

    // Copy items into subarrays
    $array1 = [];
    $array2 = [];

....
```